# Iterar sobre dataframe

Tags: r, bucle-for, dataframe

Tengo la siguiente tabla

| Año inicio | Año final | Resultado |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2000 | 2001 | 4 |
| 2002 | 2005 | 2 |

y me gustaría trasnformarla en

| Año inicio | Año final | Año | Resultado |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2000 | 2001 | 2000 | 4 |
| 2000 | 2001 | 2001 | 4 |
| 2002 | 2005 | 2002 | 2 |
| 2002 | 2005 | 2003 | 2 |
| 2002 | 2005 | 2004 | 2 |
| 2002 | 2005 | 2005 | 2 |

utilizando R.

¿Podríais ayudarme?

Comment: Bienvenido Miguel, ¿serías tan amable de añadir a la publicación el código qué has intentando hacer para qué te podamos ayudar?

Comment: Bienvenido  a Stack Overflow en español, te sugiero que hagas el [tour] y de paso ganes tu primer medalla, también es muy importante que leas [ask] para poder mejorar tu pregunta y que sea bien recibida por la comunidad mejorando así, tus chances de obtener buenas respuestas.